# In javac's source code, what is the purpose of traversing from a type to a symbol to its type?

Tags: javac

In the source code for `javac`, I have seen idioms of this form:

```
Type t = ...;

// Now let's say I want to, say, get its supertype. The idiom seems to be:
Object o = t.tsym.type.supertype_field;

// ...rather than:
Object o = t.supertype_field;
```

I understand that certain `Type`s and `Symbol`s are circular dependencies.  That is, every non-error `ClassType`, for example, has a `ClassSymbol`, and every non-error `ClassSymbol` has a `ClassType`, even though logically types precede symbols (during construction everything is twiddled to point to each other).

I also understand hazily that there may be various errors during compilation such that a given `Type` may actually be an `ErrorType` and I suppose may have different information associated with it.

What kind of canonicalizing is being accomplished by saying `t.tsym.type.something` rather than just `t.something`?

If (to reduce mental load) I pretend that errors never exist (so all, say, `ClassType`s have `ClassSymbol`s and vice versa), when is there a substantive difference between accessing `t.something` and `t.tsym.type.something`?

There is a [concrete example](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+37/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L2531) in the [`supertype(Type)` method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+37/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L2531).

Comment: In the concrete example I cite above, I think perhaps [this call](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+37/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L2533) is responsible for the canonicalization gymnastics: `classBound(Type)` will [occasionally return new `ClassType`s](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-18+37/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L2765-L2766).